# Set permissions to specific node in php

Tags: 7, views, users

Is there any way to add a role permission to specific node? I have a block-view Home slider, and I want to **add a php validation to a specific slide**.

I have to edit the `node.tpl` of my slide ? Or maybe the view output `tpl`? I'm in a Drupal 7 installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specify custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

[Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit
>   and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions'
>   permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to
>   grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set
>   default access controls per content type, and also define which roles
>   are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.

If you want to add it by custom code use `hook_node_access`

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  // We are interested to existing objects. When the node is being created, Drupal passed the node type instead of the node object. 
  if (is_object($node)) {
    $check = (
      ($node->type == 'node condition')         );
    if ($check) {
      if ($account->uid == $node->uid) {
        return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
      }
      else {
        return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
      }
    }
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

THe [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) Module should allow you to do this, by granting/restricting access by role or user.

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set default access controls per content type, and also define which roles are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.

See if that does it for you.

Comment: I have installed it, but in this case I need to set view permission based on a profile custom field.